# How do I get an idempotent value for binary functions, in a templated way?

Tags: c++, templates, accumulator, idempotent

In my code, I would like to use std::plus, std::multiplies and friends - to do some accumulation generically, i.e. pass the functor and then apply it to a sequence of elements for the result. Now, instead of just special-casing the first two elements (i.e.

```
MyFunctor op;
my_acc = op(arr[0] + arr[1])
for(int i = 2; i < length; i++) my_acc = op(my_acc, arr[i]);
```

I would like to initialize `my_acc` with an idempotent value:

```
MyFunctor op;
my_acc = get_idempotent<decltype(arr[0]),MyFunctor>();
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) my_acc = op(my_acc, arr[i]);
```

e.g. 0 for addition with integers, 1 for multiplication and so on. Is there some standard mechanism to obtain such values? Should I roll my own?

**Notes:**

- I know not all functors must have idempotents, even not all symmetric ones; let there be an error in those cases.

Comment: Your design forces `MyFunctor` to be a struct/class. (as if it is a function, you cannot distinguish `plus` from `multiplies` (`T (*)(const T&, const T&)` in both cases) (and retrieve type of lambda for your usage seems difficult)). So you may add information in the class.

Comment: @Jarod42 he also said that he want to work with standard library faclities. Which are not really extendable.

Comment: Nothing is the standard. The existing [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) "cheats" by having the caller supply the initial value.

Comment: You probably mean *neutral*, not *idempotent*. Neutrals are idempotents, but in general there may be much more strange idempotents.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such facility in standard library. In fact there is template function in standard library which often used with idempotent values: `std::accumulate`; and it requires user to provide idempotent value himself.

You can provide `get_idempotent` template class, specialize it for standard functors, and require user to specialize it for any user defined functor. Like `iterator_traits`, `allocator_traits`, `numeric_limits`, etc. Absence of such specialization should be an error (`staic_assert`?)

Comment: And nothing in Boost, either?

Comment: @einpoklum I highly doubt it. I looked in its math libraries and didn't found anything.